# Mongoose findById is returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have this schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TreeSchema = new Schema({
}, { collection: 'treeLocations' });

var TreeDetailsSchema = new Schema({
}, { collection: 'treeInfo' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tree', TreeSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('TreeDetail', TreeDetailsSchema, "treeInfo");
```

And I am calling by ID like this:

```
var TreeDetails = require('./app/models/tree').model('TreeDetail');
router.route('/api/trees/:tree_id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        TreeDetails.findById(req.params.tree_id, function(err, treedetail) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(treedetail);
        });
    });
```

For some reason - `http://localhost:3000/api/trees/5498517ab68ca1ede0612d0a` which is a real tree, is returning `null`

Something that might help you help me:

- I was following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4
- The only thing I can think of that changed is that I have a collection name. Might that be it?

Answer (score 1):

The step that I don't see is how you actually connect to MongoDB and after that, how you get the Model from the connection.

```
//  connect to MongoDB
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database');

//  now obtain the model through db, which is the MongoDB connection
TreeDetails = db.model('TreeDetails');
```

This last step is how you associate your model with the connected mongo database.

More info on [Mongoose.model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model)

There are several ways to establish a connection to MongoDB with mongoose, the tutorial uses:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o');`

(Personally I prefer the more explicit `mongoose.createConnection` as shown in the example)

(I used mongoose *4.3.1* for this example)

---

My steps to reproduce, in order to provide a working example (without creating a webservice for it):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    TreeDetails, db;

//  create the model schema
mongoose.model('TreeDetails', mongoose.Schema({
    //  ..  your field definitions
}, {collection: 'treeInfo'}));

db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@host/example');
TreeDetails = db.model('TreeDetails');

TreeDetails.findById('5671ac9217fb1730bb69e8bd', function(error, document) {
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }

    console.log(document);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - to clarify - isn't this (in my code) what does the step you say I'm missing?

module.exports = mongoose.model('TreeDetail', TreeDetailsSchema, "treeInfo");

var TreeDetails = require('./app/models/tree').model('TreeDetail');

Comment: The `module.exports = mongoose.model(...)` part registers your model to mongoose, it does not actually connect to the database. I've updated the answer to clarify the connections some more

Comment: Hey @Rogier - thanks for your help but it's still coming up null.

Comment: What if you put the code below the line in my answer (make sure to doublecheck the id) in a separate file (e.g. `test.js`) and run it (`node test.js`)? Because that worked fine for me. If that does work, you could try to comment the line `module.exports = mongoose.model('Tree', TreeSchema);`, not sure if it helps, but it seems odd to have multiple `module.exports = ...` in one file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var TreeDetails = require('./app/models/tree').model('TreeDetail');
```

try:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    TreeDetails = mongoose.model('TreeDetail');
```

Defining the collection name shouldn't give you any issues. It's just what the collection will be called in the database / when using the mongo shell.

And just to be sure, try logging *req.params.tree_id* before calling findById to make sure it's coming through as you suspect.

Comment: Hey thanks - Just tried this - it doesn't seem to be the issue. tree_id is fine, too. It's in string form - which is how it is in the db, too.

The weirdest thing is that this worked fine with the scotch.io bear example.